# Log user in after confirming account using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise for account registration and confirmation. When I click on the 'Confirm my account' link, it just confirms the account without redirecting me to a new page or anything. How can I customize Devise so that it would log me in or redirect to a new page after confirmation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite after_sign_in_path_for method.
You can do it in your application controller.
What I have done is,

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(scope)
  if scope.is_a?(User)
    '#'
  elsif scope.is_a?(Admin)
     '#'
  else
     super
  end
end
```